# Throwing exception when creating F# record with invalid values

Tags: f#

I am new to F#, so forgive me if this is a newbie question.

I'm working through Vladimir Khorikov's Pluralsight course "Domain Driven Design in Practice".  His examples are implemented using C#, so for practice, I'm attempting to implement them in F#.

He has a class "Money", which, in F#, looks like this:

```
 type Money =
    {
        OneCentCount: int;
        TenCentCount: int;
        QuarterCount: int;
        OneDollarCount: int;
        FiveDollarCount: int;
        TwentyDollarCount: int;
    }
```

I'm fine with this, and can implement different operations on this class, although some of them become a little clumsy since record types have no constructor in F#.  (I.e., while I would like to be able to say

```
let money1 = Money(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

that throws an error that there's no constructor for Money.  So I have to do

```
let money1 = Money { 
    OneCentCount = 1; 
    TenCentCount = 2; 
    QuarterCount = 3; 
    OneDollarCount = 4; 
    FiveDollarCount = 5; 
    TwentyDollarCount = 6}
```

Now, however, he's moving on to testing, and he wants a test that throws an InvalidOp exception if you attempt to create a Money record with any of the values negative - a reasonable requirement.

But since there's no constructor for the Money type, I can't figure out where to put the code to test for invalid values and throw the exception.

Can anyone give me some pointers?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider an `invalid` value for this Money record?

Comment: As set forth in the test requirements that I'm attempting to implement, an invalid value is one in which any of the values are negative.  You can't, for example, have a Money amount with -10 pennies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick you can do is shadowing:

```
type Money =
    {
        OneCentCount: int;
        TenCentCount: int;
        QuarterCount: int;
        OneDollarCount: int;
        FiveDollarCount: int;
        TwentyDollarCount: int;
    } 

 let Money (a, b, c, d, e, f) =  
   { OneCentCount = a; 
    TenCentCount = b; 
    QuarterCount = c; 
    OneDollarCount = d; 
    FiveDollarCount = e; 
    TwentyDollarCount = f}
```

Then in your function `Money(a,b,c,d,e,f)`, you can put the appropriate validation logic. For example, we can not allow negative values for `OneCentCount`:

```
let Money (a, b, c, d, e, f) =  
    if a < 0 then
        raise(invalidArg("a is required to be a positive value"))
    else
        {  OneCentCount = a; 
            TenCentCount = b; 
            QuarterCount = c; 
            OneDollarCount = d; 
            FiveDollarCount = e; 
            TwentyDollarCount = f}
```

Answer (score 4):

A typical approach would be to have a smart constructor on the type defined as a static member (example on a simplified type):

```
type Money =
    {
        OneCentCount: int;
        TenCentCount: int;
    }
    static member Create (oneCent, tenCent) =
        let throwOnNegative field v =
            if v < 0 then invalidOp (sprintf "Negative value for %s" field) else v
        {
            OneCentCount = oneCent |> throwOnNegative "OneCentCount"
            TenCentCount = tenCent |> throwOnNegative "TenCentCount"
        }
```

Any sort of validation logic can go into the body of Create function.

Answer (score 2):

The existing two answers provide a good illustration of the basic idea - you need to hide some of the internals of the data type and provide a custom operation for creating values that implements the checks.

One thing that might be useful in your example is to separate the checking from the `Money` type - following the approach in the existing answers, you have to repeat the check for every single field which is quite tedious. Alternatively, you could define a type `Count` which use the same hiding technique to allow only positive values and then define your record in terms of `Count`:

```
type Count = 
  private { Count : int }
  member x.Value = x.Count

let Count n = 
  if n < 0 then invalidOp "Negative count!"
  else { Count = n }
```

Now you can use just an ordinary record:

```
type Money =
  { OneCentCount: Count
    TenCentCount: Count
    QuarterCount: Count
    OneDollarCount: Count
    FiveDollarCount: Count
    TwentyDollarCount: Count }
```

When creating a value of the record, it works as an ordinary record, but you have to create all the `Count` values using the `Count` function which does the checks:

```
let money = 
  { OneCentCount = Count 10
    TenCentCount = Count 10
    QuarterCount = Count -1
    OneDollarCount = Count 10
    FiveDollarCount = Count 10
    TwentyDollarCount = Count 10 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach I typically employ for DDD in F# is to create a type for each distinct combination of business rules I want to apply:

`[<Struct>] type MonetaryUnitCount = private MonetaryUnitCount of int`

These types have private constructors, so we can control how they are created, exposing only a single function to create each type:

```
module MonetaryUnitCount =
    let create count =
        if count < 0
        then Error "Count must be positive"
        else Ok (MonetaryUnitCount count)
```

Then, each record type would also have a private constructor and a corresponding `create` function that calls the correct `create` function for each field, validating the data as it goes:

```
type Money =
    private {
        OneCentCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
        TenCentCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
        QuarterCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
        OneDollarCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
        FiveDollarCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
        TwentyDollarCount: MonetaryUnitCount 
    } 

module Money =
    let create (a, b, c, d, e, f) =
        MonetaryUnitCount.create a
        |> Result.bind (fun m -> MonetaryUnitCount.create b |> Result.map (fun n -> m, n))
        |> Result.bind (fun (m, n) -> MonetaryUnitCount.create c |> Result.map (fun o -> m, n, o))
        |> Result.bind (fun (m, n, o) -> MonetaryUnitCount.create d |> Result.map (fun p -> m, n, o, p))
        |> Result.bind (fun (m, n, o, p) -> MonetaryUnitCount.create e |> Result.map (fun q -> m, n, o, p, q))
        |> Result.bind (fun (m, n, o, p, q) -> MonetaryUnitCount.create f |> Result.map (fun r -> m, n, o, p, q, r))
        |> Result.map (fun (m, n, o, p, q, r) -> 
            {
                OneCentCount = m
                TenCentCount = n
                QuarterCount = o
                OneDollarCount = p
                FiveDollarCount = q
                TwentyDollarCount = r
            })
```

This way you either end up with a successful result with your `Money` populated, or an error with the validation failure.  There is no way to construct an instance of `MonetaryUnitCount` with a negative value, and there is no way to construct an instance of `Money` with an invalid `MonetaryUnitCount`, so any instance that exists must be valid.

This syntax can be considerably simplified by using a Computation Expression for binding the `Result` type automatically, or enhanced by using applicatives to collect all the validation errors.

Comment: This syntax can be considerably simplified by not mapping to tuples of increasing length `MonetaryUnitCount.create a |> Result.bind (fun m -> MonetaryUnitCount.create b |> Result.bind (fun n -> ...`, and possibly a bit more by employing the monadic operator `let (>>=) a f = Result.bind f a`.